# How to convert Android strings.xml into Qt linguist .ts file?

Tags: android, qt, translation

We'd like to simplify translation jobs by converging and converting them into a single format, for example Qt linguist files. There is a loot `lconvert`, but that doesn't support Android strings.xml

Is it possible to convert Android strings.xml into Qt linguist .ts files back and forth?